# IPv6 ICMP rules for AWS Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, ipv6, aws-ec2, icmpv6

I'm in the process of configuring IPv6 ICMP rules in my AWS Security Group, specifically for an EC2 instance. I need to allow ICMP traffic for the PTMUD protocol and other related protocols. In the Security Group settings, I have options for IPv4 ICMP rules, but I don't see a clear counterpart for IPv6.

In the Security Group settings, I have the following options:

- `Custom ICMP - IPv4` (which is what I want for IPv4, but I'm looking for an IPv6 counterpart)
- `All ICMP - IPv4`
- `All ICMP - IPv6`

What is the best practice or suggestion for allowing ICMP traffic for IPv6 in an AWS Security Group? These ICMP rules are required for PTMUD and other parts of the protocol, many of which are internal and may not be directly related to Security Group settings.

Any guidance on configuring these rules for IPv6 would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Read _[RFC 4890, Recommendations for Filtering ICMPv6 Messages in Firewalls](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4890)_.

Comment: @RonMaupin The problem with the AWS rules is that for IPv6, ICMP seems to be _all_ or _nothing_.